# sending email with emailJS when deployed on Heroku

Tags: email, heroku

I'm having trouble sending email with emailJS when deploying the site on heroku.
it works perfectly fine in development
the error says that the service id is invalid but i tested it and it works...

````
init("user_dvXegxEb11cRFMAuFpf6J");

const ContactScreen = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
    const [emailsender, setEmailsender] = useState('');
    const [question, setQuestion] = useState('');
 
const templateParams = {
          from_name: emailsender,
          name: name,
          to_name:"Yves",
          subject: subject,
          message: question
        };


////SEND FORM TO EMAIL => 'emailjs'////  
const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        setName("");
        setEmailsender("");
        setSubject("");
        setQuestion("");
   
    emailjs.send(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID,process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID,templateParams,process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID)
     .then(
              function(response) {
                  toast.success(" Your message has successfully sent!", {
                  position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
                  pauseOnHover: true
               })
                  console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
                  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID);
              },
              function(err) {
                  toast.error("Your message was not able to be sent");
                  console.log(err);
              })
        };```
````

Comment: Hi... did you manage to solve it? I'v just had the same problem